# Android string-array display Percent Sign

Tags: android, arrays, xml

I have a string-array in my strings.xml file that has multiple items in it.  Only one of the items has multiple percetage "%" symbols that needs to be displayed.  Seems none of the advice on how to escape it works at all.  \%, %% or using formatted="false" on either the string-array or the items tags.  When I use \% Eclipses shows errors with the item, if I use %% then Eclipse is fine it runs but then the text displays two percent signs "%%".  So any ideas on how to escape % sign in strings.xml?

```
<string-array name="details">
     <item>Placement of things</item>
     <item>Percentage of times placed is 30% 
         and percentage of times release 50%</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: apparently there is a bug in the escaping multiple percentages in the same string item in string-array.  I can use &#37; once and it works if I use more than once in the same item then it errors.

Comment: Strange, i can add perfectly add "%", no problem with that. Can you explain exactly what does your code do?

Comment: There's nothing to explain I want to display the 2 strings verbatim.  Its Eclipse that is giving me the errors and I can't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently using an older version of eclipse and not having the latest SDK for android will produce this problem.  I upgraded eclipse to 3.6.2 and made sure to install the latest version android sdk r10. So hope this helps someone and saves them time as I wasted a couple of hours trying to fix/find the answer.

So the answer to this question is you can use just a single % sign multiple times in a string array item without having to escape it, double up or use CDATA as long as you have the most recent versions of the SDK and Eclipse.

Comment: Funny answer even though correct has a negative rating...not sure why someone would disagree since this was the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Are your ADT plugin and SDK updated? 
Mine are updated and doesn't show this error. Works like a charm with just one %.

Anyway, have you tried to put the string inside a CDATA?

```
<string-array name="details">
     <item>Placement of things</item>
     <item><![CDATA[Percentage of times placed is 30% 
             and percentage of times release 50%]]></item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: Hmm I get errors, I am pretty sure I have the latest updates.  Seems weird I tried the CDATA approach and it errored too in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

A tricky method is to use unicode character of percent sign

```
U+FE6A ﹪ small percent sign (HTML &#65130; )
U+FF05 ％ full-width percent sign (HTML &#65285;)
```

In XML you can define as following

```
    <string-array name="details">
         <item>Placement of things</item>
         <item>Percentage of times placed is 30&#65130; 
             and percentage of times release 50&#65130;</item>
    </string-array>
```

[Percent Sign on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent_sign#Unicode)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, but nothing to do, nothing worked for me on JB 4.1.2.
Here's what i tried:

```
<string-array name="percentage">
    <item>a. 100%</item>            <!-- unknownFormatConversionException -->
    <item>b. 90&#37;</item>         <!-- unknownFormatConversionException -->
    <item>c. 80%%</item>            <!-- "somewhere" a double %% appears -->
    <item>d. 60\%</item>            <!-- no % appears -->
    <item>e. 40\%%</item>           <!-- unknownFormatConversionException -->
    <item>f. 30%\%</item>           <!-- unknownFormatConversionException -->
    <item><![CDATA[g. 20%]]></item> <!-- unknownFormatConversionException -->
    <item formatter="false>h. 10%</item>    <!-- unknownFormatConversionException -->
</string-array>
```

Using emlators i've seen that before ICS 4.0 everything works great, like in my Galaxy-S GB 2.3.5, while using ICS and above the unknownFormatConversionExceptions appear, just like on my Nexus S JB 4.1.2.
Finally, [this](https://bradford.la/2013/android-sdk-unknownformatconversionexception) was my final decision: omitting percentage symbol at all!

```
<item>a. 100</item>
<item>b. 90</item>
...
```

It's just a very rough workaround, but at least i can go on working!
I'm using ADT Build: v22.0.1-685705 under Ubuntu 13.04
testing devices: Nexus S JB 4.1.2, Samsung Galaxy S GB 2.3.5

Comment: Wow this is still an issue with a more recent android build?  Well its a Samsung and they do things differently.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was declaring a new string in strings.xml with the percent symbols and attribute *formatted="false"*

```
<string name="percents" formatted="false">10&#37; is not 20&#37;</string
```

And then in arrays.xml

```
<string-array name="my_array">
    <item>@string/percents</item>
    ...
```